# Validação de lista com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de validar uma lista usando só JavaScript.
Se o item já estiver na lista deve aparecer um alerta com a posição do item e se o item não estiver na lista deve ser incluído.

O problema atual é que ao executar o código o alert está sendo executado mesmo na primeira vez que o item aparece e se eu tentar informar uma segunda vez ele ainda entra na lista.
vejam:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<h1>Lista de casamento</h1>
Digite o nome do convidado: <br>
<input type="text"  id="campoConvidado">
<button onclick="listaConvidados();">Adicionar</button>
<hr><br>
<p  id="quantidadeConvidado">No momento sua lista está com [0] convidado(s)</p>

<script>
    var lista= [];
//criei uma única função para alinhar a lista no html e fazer as validações
    function listaConvidados()
    {
        var recebeNome= campoConvidado.value;
        lista.push(recebeNome);
        quantidadeConvidado.innerHTML= `No momento sua lista está com [${lista.length}] convidado(s)<br>
        <br> Nomes: <br> 
        <ol>
            <li>
                ${lista.join("</li><br><li>")}
            </li>
        </ol>`   
        if(recebeNome.trim()=="") //aqui quero que caso seja um campo em branco apareça o alerta a baixo.
        {
            alert("digite um nome para inserir na lista")
        }
        if (lista.includes(recebeNome) == false) // Inclui o novo item na lista
        {
        }
        else    
        {
            var posicao = lista.indexOf(recebeNome);
            alert("Nome informado já está na sua lista. Ele é o convidado de número [" + (posicao+1)+"]");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Agradeço se alguém tiver paciência para me explicar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O maior problema é que você insere sempre o elemento na lista independentemente da situação:

```
function listaConvidados()
{
    var recebeNome= campoConvidado.value;
    lista.push(recebeNome);
```

Repare que mesmo que já exista ou que o nome esteja vazio vai adicionar na mesma pois é a primeira coisa a fazer. Mas você só quer adicionar se for valido, e por isso tem que testar os dois casos de inválido (vazio e já existir) antes de adicionar.

Curiosamente, você até já tem o código todo para isso só que está no local errado.

Faça antes assim:

```js
var lista= [];

function listaConvidados()
{
    var recebeNome= campoConvidado.value;
    
    if(recebeNome.trim() == "") //primeiro testa o primeiro caso de invalido
    {
        alert("digite um nome para inserir na lista")
    }
    else if (lista.includes(recebeNome)) //depois o segundo caso de invalido
    {
        alert("Nome informado já está na sua lista. Ele é o convidado de número [" + (lista.indexOf(recebeNome)+1)+"]");
    }
    else //se está tudo valido então adiciona e mostra o html apropriado
    {
        lista.push(recebeNome);
        quantidadeConvidado.innerHTML= `No momento sua lista está com [${lista.length}] convidado(s)<br>
        <br> Nomes: <br> 
        <ol>
            <li>
                ${lista.join("</li><br><li>")}
            </li>
        </ol>`               
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Lista de casamento</h1>
Digite o nome do convidado: <br>
<input type="text"  id="campoConvidado">
<button onclick="listaConvidados();">Adicionar</button>
<hr><br>
<p id="quantidadeConvidado">No momento sua lista está com [0] convidado(s)</p>
```

Note que neste meu exemplo os dois primeiros ifs que testam casos invalidos não tem o `push` e por isso a lista nunca é modificada.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela luz.
Depois de um tempo revendo o código não tinha visto isso. o que me faltou foi a lógica nesse caso. 
Estava inserindo pra depois validar, quando era só fazer a ordem oposta.
Novamente agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: @Almeida Sem problema, estamos cá para ajudar :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Você não referencia o elemento através do `document.getElementById()`, para então pegar o valor do campo.
2. Você insere o nome na lista primeiro e depois verifica se o campo está vazio.
3. Você verifica duas vezes se o elemento já existe no seu array.

Seu codigo deve ficar +- assim

```
const lista = []

document.getElementById('inserirConvidado').onclick = function () {
    const recebeNome = document.getElementById('campoConvidado').value

  // caso seja um campo em branco apareça o alerta a baixo.
  if(recebeNome.trim() === ''){
    return alert('digite um nome para inserir na lista')
  }
  // caso o nome ja esteja na lista aparece o alerta com a posicao do nome na lista.
  if(lista.includes(recebeNome)){
    return alert(`Nome informado já está na sua lista. Ele é o convidado de número [${lista.indexOf(recebeNome) + 1}]`) 
  }

  lista.push(recebeNome)
  document.getElementById('quantidadeConvidado').innerHTML= `No momento sua lista está com [${lista.length}] convidado(s)<br>
        <br> Nomes: <br> 
        <ol>
            <li>
                ${lista.join("</li><br><li>")}
            </li>
        </ol>`
}
```

Veja que eu verifico se o campo está vazio, e depois se o convidado já está na lista, para depois inserir o nome.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda! eu estava validando somente depois de incluir. agradeço pela dica.